# Add existing SQL code to Azure DevOps Git and automate further deployment to production

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I have an existing Azure SQL Server with Development, Testing and Production DB's. I need to copy SQL code to Azure DevOps Git Repo and automate further process (check files and deploy to Prod). Or in other words, to implement a version control  that should allow to create a forks, change SQL db objects definition and control all changes. Are there any best practices to do so? Newbi to Azure DevOps Git...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we follow CICD for Azure SQL database in our project:

1. Branches
   We have 4 environments: Dev,test,UAT,Prod
   So we have the below branching strategy hierarchy :
   a) Features branches : For diff developments
   b) Test : When we want to deploy our code to Test Env, we raise a PR from Feature branch to Test
   c) UAT : raise Pull request from Test to UAT
   d) Master: For Prod

We have created Azure SQL database project for maintaining our SQL code objects.

For actual CICD :

2. Build Pipeline

Use Visual studio build task to build the SQL solution and publish the DACPAC artifacts in Build location

[image]

3. Release Pipeline :

Use Azure SQL database deployment task to publish the DACPAC to the Env server:

[image]